# navigate between views using hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, query-string, multiview

I have a muliview control with 2 views(view1 and view2) and each view has a datagrid. In view1 datagrid i have a column(customerid) with hyperlink control(not a link) and user can click on it and it has to navigate to view2 datagrid by passing the querystring "customer id". So how to pass the querystring value to another view?And is it possible to append the querystring to another view.

Answer (score 0):

Format your hyperlinks this way you can do that in GridView bind data event:

```
YourPageWithMultiViews.aspx?customerID=3322&MultiViewID=2
```

In PageLoad event:

```
if(Request["MultiViewID"] == "2")
{
MultiView1.SetActiveView(view2);
}
else
{
MultiView1.SetActiveView(view1);
}
```